# Using QTWebKit to display a website stored in memory

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit

Currently I have my HTML, JS, CSS, graphics, etc stored locally on hard disk and access them using `QWebFrame::SetUrl( QUrl::fromLocalFile( "appFolder\html\index.html" ))`.  At some point I am going to need to encrypt the locally stored files so I'm looking for a way to either decrypt them as they're requested or to decrypt them all into memory and access them that way.

I know I can use `QWebFrame::setContent( htmlData )` to load the HTML from memory so I can load the encrypted HTML file, decrypt it in memory and then display it that way, but how would I go about the other data (JS, CSS, graphics, etc) which is currently stored in subfolders?

Alternatively, is there a way I can intercept requests for access to all the HTML, JS, CSS, etc files and decrypt them as they're loaded?

By using my own `NetworkAccessManager` I can intercept calls to `createRequest` so I can see when each file is being loaded, but I can't see how to use this to decrypt the data on the fly.  I can also connect a slot function to the `finished(QNetworkReply*)` signal, but at that point the data has already been read - the `QIODevice`'s current position is pointing to the end of the file.

I'd be very grateful for any advice or pointers in the right direction.

Comment: You should inherit QNetworkReply class and use it in QNetworkAccesManager::createRequest(). In this new class you can modify raw data (in your case decrypt html) before finished() was emitted.

Comment: @Johnny : Thanks - that certainly put me on the right tracks.  It was still far from straight forward to implement, but it was good to be pointed in the right direction.  Looking at QFileNetworkReply.cpp was also very useful to see how they used QNetworkReply with local file access.  If you want to elaborate a little on your comment in an answer I'll mark it as accepted.  If not, I'll put the outline of the code up as the answer.  Thanks again - you definitely helped me get the problem sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your case the best solution is to inherit *QNetworkReply* class and use this new class in reimplemented `QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest()` function.

In general, you should reimplement next virtual functions of *QNetworkReply*: 
`bytesAvailable()`, `readData(char *data, qint64 maxSize)`, `close()`, `abort()`.

For example, `readData` should be the folowing:

```
qint64 NetworkReplyEx::readData(char *data, qint64 maxSize)
{
    return m_buffer.read(data, maxSize);
}
```

where `m_buffer` is already decrypted data.

Also you need to add all necessary logic in this class to get encrypted data, decrypt this data...
In the end you should manually emit `finished()` signal inside new class, so `QWebView` or other related class will get decrypted html.