# Render QImage in QWebView/QWebPage straight from buffer?

Tags: python, web, pyside, qimage, qwebpage

I have a QImage buffer which I would like to render in a QWebPage.

The HTML in the web page has a tag for the image file.

Rather than saving QImage to disk and then using an xml parser to update the `href` in the html, is it possible to render the QImage straight from the buffer into the QWebPage(/QWebView)?

I have seen a few things about QtWebKit 'Bridge' that suggests this is possible, but no concrete examples.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know protocol about duplicate questions, but this has been asked & answered for a similar scenario before:

[Using QTWebKit to display a website stored in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427340/using-qtwebkit-to-display-a-website-stored-in-memory)

Please be aware though that this requires you to encode your QImage in a format understood by the web-view, such as PNG.

I think using a temp-file and directing the img-tag to that is by far the fastest & easiest way.

Comment: That is not even remotely the same question. I am asking if I can render from a QImage directly into the HTML content of a QWebpage without first rendering the QImage to disk and templating.

Comment: Then you obviously didn't understand the other answer - not even remotely... Because it is exactly about serving content from memory, not via network/disk. An href-attribute in an image will trigger a network-request which by the answer linked to you can intercept, and serve the content by whatever means you see fit. E.g. providing it from a QImage. But of course your free to ignore it. Good luck!

Comment: The reference should indeed set the asker on the right track. But still this is far from an exhausting answer. An example would be nice.

Comment: True. But I don't have one, and don't want to cook one up. So - meta-question - should I not give answers and instead just put a link into a comment? Will then do next time.